# iOS Facebook library login

Tags: objective-c, facebook

I just downloaded the facebook library for iOS at this URL https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk

I managed to run the sample app just fine, however, when I click on the login button, it actually opens the login screen in a browser.

How can I prevent this?

Thanks,
Tee

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out.

In Facebook.m, change

```
safariAuth:YES
```

to

```
safariAuth:NO
```

Comment: Facebook does this so that a user will be automatically authenticated with Facebook (i.e. they won't need to enter their email and password) if they have already authenticated with a different application. If you turn off Safari mode I would double check that the users don't need to re-enter their credentials.